# Print frequency of words, in a sentence, in a single line

Tags: python

I have a sentence "The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog", and I have counted the number of times each word occurs in this sentence. The output should be like this:

```
brown:1,dog:1,fox:1,jumps:1,lazy:1,over:1,quick:1,the:2
```

There should be no spaces between the characters in this output, and there should be commas between the words/numbers. 
The output from my program looks like this:

```
,brown:1,dog:1,fox:1,jumps:1,lazy:1,over:1,quick:1,the:2
```

I find that there is a comma place before 'brown'. Is there an easier way to print this?

```
    filename = os.path.basename(path)


    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        fline = f.read()     
        fwords = fline.split()  

        allwords = [word.lower() for word in fwords]
        sortwords = list(set(allwords))


    r = sorted(sortwords, key=str.lower)

    finalwords = ','.join(r)

    sys.stdout.write(str(finalwords))
    print '\n'

    countlist = {}
    for word in allwords:
        try: countlist[word] += 1
        except KeyError: countlist[word] = 1       

    for c,num in sorted(countlist.items()):
        sys.stdout.write(",{:}:{:}".format(c, num))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple alternate ways of making the word list. First, a one-liner:

```
countlist = {word:allwords.count(word) for word in allwords}
```

As pointed out by DSM, that method can be slow with long lists. An alternate would be to use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from itertools import defaultdict
countlist = defaultdict(int)
for word in allwords:
    countlist[word] += 1
```

---

For output, join individual word counts with a `,`, which avoids having one at the beginning:

```
sys.stdout.write(",".join(["{:}:{:}".format(key, value) for key, value in countlist .items()]))
```

Comment: The OP already has a dictionary of the word counts -- `countlist`, which is admittedly confusingly named.  And the OP's method of counting is linear, so it'll be faster than `.count` for lots of words.

Comment: @DSM, I know OP has a dictionary of the word counts. This is an alternate, possibly easier (but yes admittedly slower on very long lists) way of making it. I guess I'll add an example of using `defaultdict` as well.